# inbound-channel-adapter cannot ignore "directory" tag element when using custom scanner

Tags: spring-integration

I use spring integration 4.2.6.RELEASE and try to create custom file watcher

something like this:

```
 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesInAdapter" directory="#{pojoUtil.sourceRootDir}" auto-create-directory="true"
                                  channel="filesInChannel" scanner="watchDirectoryScanner" auto-startup="true">
    <int:poller ref="globalPoller"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>


<!-- directory scanner org.springframework.integration.file.WatchServiceDirectoryScanner -->
<!--id.lsa.scb.spring.integration.scanner.CustomScanner-->
<bean id="nioLocker" class="org.springframework.integration.file.locking.NioFileLocker"/>

<bean id="watchDirectoryScanner" class="id.lsa.scb.spring.integration.scanner.AdrFileScanner">
    <constructor-arg value="#{pojoUtil.sourceRootDir}"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="filter" ref="compositeFilter"/>
    <property name="locker" ref="nioLocker"/>
    <property name="adrUtil" ref="pojoUtil"/>
</bean>
```

How to ignore directory tag element in int-file:inbound-channel-adapter? Because I thought we don't need that if the directory initiated in custom the file scanner. I have customize the file scanner so it can registering a list of directory into file watcher without need to watch the root of that list.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved in [4.3 which should be released in the next week or so](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3989). It's available in [the release candidate](https://spring.io/blog/2016/05/12/spring-integration-4-3-0-release-candidate-available).

For now, you need to specify the directory in both places.

Comment: Thanks Gary I'll try the latest version